# Dividing every column element by its counterpart in another column in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

If I have a simple matrix

```
A = [1 3 ; 4 3 ; 6 12]
```

And then go

```
A(:,3) = (A(:,1)+A(:,2))
```

then every element in column 3 will contain the sum of its counterparts in columns 1 and 2.

However, when I go

```
A(:,3) = (A(:,1)/A(:,2))
```

I get an error message `Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.` Google searches did not reveal an enlightening explanation of this error message. Can anyone here help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`A(:,3) = (A(:,1)/A(:,2))`
is actually doing a matrix division.

I'm guessing you want to the divide corresponding elements of the vectors. In this case you need to add a dot to the division. So the code you want would read...

`A(:,3) = (A(:,1)./A(:,2))`

See http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arithmeticoperators.html for a pretty good explanation.